# Advice on what type of model should be considered for treatment data

Tags: r, self-study, predictive-models

I have a dataset with four variables: treatment, subjectID, tumor size, and time.  There are four different treatments with 10 subjects assigned to each treatment.  The subjectID denotes which subject the current observation is for and tumor size records the current size of the tumor.  I have the tumor size for time periods 0,1,2, and 3.  So I essentially have four observations of tumor size for each subject, and my goal is to predict the tumor size for periods 4 and 5.  Im asking if anyone has any advice for what models should be considered for the highest accuracy.  I ran a mixed effects model but it was singular probably due to how few observations I have for each subject.

```
lmer(Tumor ~ Experiment + Time + (1| subjectID),data=train)
```

Comment: Were the 4 treatments randomly assigned among the 40 patients? Do you expect the tumor size (however measured) to change linearly with time?

Comment: Yes they were randomly assigned to each treatment.  The tumor size does change over time  but the magnitude is different per treatment group.

Answer (score 0):

As the great US philosopher [L.P. Berra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogi_Berra) [might have said](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/261863-it-s-tough-to-make-predictions-especially-about-the-future): "It's tough to make predictions, especially about the future." That's particularly true for tumor sizes. Very often, a patient's tumor seems to respond initially to treatment as the large percentage of cancer cells sensitive to the therapy are killed, but then a [fraction of therapy-resistant cancer cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumour_heterogeneity#Treatment_resistance) takes over to re-grow a (now resistant) tumor. I am thus skeptical that you will be able "to predict the tumor size for periods 4 and 5" successfully.

That said, there are a few statistical issues to address in your analysis of tumor size through time period 3. Most important, you say in a comment that "tumor size does change over time but the magnitude is different per treatment group." Your model, however, doesn't allow for that possibility. (I assume that by `Experiment` you mean "treatment group.") The model has additive effects for `Experiment` and `Time`. Thus you allow for different baseline (`Time = 0`) values among `Experiments`,* but no *differences* over time among the `Experiments`. For that you need to have an interaction term between those predictors.

Second, if you are treating `Time` as a continuous variable (0 through 3, which would be one way to try to predict values for `Time` values of 4 and 5), then you are implicitly assuming a linear change in `Tumor` over `Time`. In addition to the issues I note in the first paragraph, that will depend on how you measure the `Tumor` value: is it a linear dimension, the cross-sectional area in an image, or an estimate of tumor volume? Not all of those can necessarily be expected to change linearly with time.

Third, your random effect only allows for differences among subjects in terms of estimated baseline `Tumor` values at `Time = 0`, and even that seems to be posing problems for you. You might consider alternate approaches to handling repeated measures on the same subjects, for example multivariate regression as explained by [Fox and Weinberg](https://socialsciences.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/appendices/Appendix-Multivariate-Linear-Models.pdf) in Section 3, or generalized least squares with a flexible model for changes over time, as explained by Harrell in Chapter 7 of his [course notes](http://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf).

Before you jump ahead to writing a new model, however, first spend some time *looking at* what the data tell you about what your model needs to capture.

---

*One of the advantages of a randomized trial is that it will tend to average out any differences in baseline tumor size among `Experiment` groups, making this term potentially less important than in other designs.